# Uncaught TypeError: this.zoomControl.draggerUp is not a function with anmap.js

Tags: dictionary

I am using this plugin https://hy.wordpress.org/plugins/ideal-interactive-map/ for interactive maps and suddenly I got this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.zoomControl.draggerUp is not a function
```

I dont know why.pLease help me

Comment: where is this error from?

Comment: I found the solution.It was because of this style  `#mapdiv {
   float:left;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.The error was because of this style given to the map container div

```
#mapdiv { float:left; }
```